# MS Access Crosstab Query parameters

Tags: ms-access, forms, parameters, crosstab

Is there a way to reference a form's combo/text box within the query like a select query?

I usually use something like this in a select query's criteria:

```
like forms!frmMain.qTitleofSomething&*   (access adds the brackets for me)
```

but this does not work in a crosstab query?? which I just found out. is there a way to accomplish the same kind of parameter control without setting up multiple crosstabs?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you supply the SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to the query if you wish to reference a form You can do this by right-clicking in the query design window or by typing it into the SQL view. You should end up with something on the lines of:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frmA]![Field1] Short;
TRANSFORM Count(tblA.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT tblA.Field2, Count(tblA.ID) AS [Total Of ID]
FROM tblA
WHERE tblA.Field1=[Forms]![frmA]![Field1]
GROUP BY tblA.Field2
PIVOT tblA.Field1;
```

*Short* refers to the data type of the field. The types are included in a drop down list available from right-clicking in the query design window and selecting Parameters.

Comment: thanks very much for this! i was pulling my hair out and you just saved me a lot of extra before and after queries!! thanks Remou!!

Comment: [Hello from 2018!] If you use a form value in a `SELECT` query and then use its result in a crosstab query it also gives an error. In this case you need to append that form field to a Parameters table of the select query.