# MS access chart with date from another form

Tags: ms-access, date-range

I am working on a project on MS access. I have to create a form in which I have a graph representing on the x-axis the time (in day) and on the y-axis the number of login of the users. Doth day and login data are stored in a table called Login. Thus I created the graph giving as Row source this table. This is the SQL code i have up to now:

```
TRANSFORM Count(LogIn.[ID]) AS CountOfID
SELECT (Format([Time],"Short Date")) AS Expr1
FROM LogIn
GROUP BY (Int([Time])), (Format([Time],"Short Date"))
PIVOT LogIn.[ID];*
```

I would like to have the x-axis, showing days, between a range (Start Date and End Date). These 2 values should be taken from another Form called RangeDate.

Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Filter criteria in CROSSTAB requires use of PARAMETERS or must specify column headings. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Param

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access Crosstab Query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139982/ms-access-crosstab-query-parameters)

Comment: I will give it a try! Thank you very much